# How to fix java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, http

I am accessing an endpoint that's meant to delete some data via an angular front-end and Spring-Boot backend, and upon calling the method, the error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $` gets thrown on my Google Chrome console. On a closer look, it also throws a `exception: "com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException"` with an error status of 500. As a result, I am unable to delete a customer's fingerprints through the API endpoint that I'm calling.

I have tried running the same endpoint from postman without any success so far.

This is the sample request I making via postman:

json:

`{
"pbuNo":"PBU689184"
}`

on Angular:

```
     this.custSvc.afisReject(customer).subscribe(data => {
      this.respo = data;
      console.log('repo', this.respo);
      if (this.respo.status === true) {
        // delete fingerprints from AFIS
        this.apiService.afisDeleteCust(this.customer.pbuno).subscribe();
        this.editMode = false;
        this.gtCustomers();
        this.blockUI.stop();
        return this.toastr.success('Customer was rejected upddated successfuly.', ' Success!');
      } else {
        this.blockUI.stop();
        return this.toastr.warning('There was problem rejecting customer details .', 'Warning!');
      }
    });

AFIS_URL = 'http://196.0.25.194:8090/otc/compas';

 afisDeleteCust(pbuno): Observable<any> {
        const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        const applicantt = { fingerPrints: [{ position: 0, base64String: '' }] };
        return this.http.post(`${this.AFIS_URL}/afis/rest/deleteapplicant`, pbuno, { headers: headers });
    }
```

Controller:

```
// reject customer end-point
@PostMapping(value = "/customers/rejected")
public ResponseEntity<?> rejectCustomer(@RequestBody Customer customer) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Rejected:: " + customer.getPbuno());
        int rejectCust = customerService.rejectCustomer(customer.getPbuno());
        if (rejectCust <= 0) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(
                    new CustomResponse(CustomResponse.APIV, 200, false, "failed to reject customer"),
                    HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(
                new CustomResponse(CustomResponse.APIV, 200, true, "Customer rejected successfully"),
                HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(
                new CustomResponse(CustomResponse.APIV, 200, false, "Server error processing request"),
                HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

The response data seems to fit the model. When I run this call with postman it returns an error 500. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: can you post the server side code for handling the /afis/rest/deleteapplicant

Comment: @TruckDriver see above updated post

Comment: is this correct endpoint ""/customers/rejected"?

Comment: Also from postman, how are you sending the data , are you selecting the type as application/json?

Comment: @TruckDriver  `"/customers/rejected"` is endpoint that I call from front-end when rejecting customer.  Upon rejecting, I then call the `this.apiService.afisDeleteCust(this.customer.pbuno).subscribe();` which is mapped to `/afis/rest/deleteapplicant`